# Security Exception with medium trust, ninject and entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject-2, medium-trust

I keep getting this exception whenever I try running my project in medium trust. The project is MVC Forum, and even though I don't need to run any of my own sites in medium trust, I figure I better make it work in the medium trust environment anyway.

I'm using Ninject for DI (the DLL that works in medium trust), and that works - the MVC controllers are loaded with constructor injection as expected.

The "funny" thing is that the method (in my code) that fails, take 2 arguments, these are both loaded from the database using entity framework, so I have no idea why this fails, when entity framework clearly already work in other parts of the code.

What is the reason behind this exception? It's like looking for the famous needle in a haystack.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.DemandMemberAccess() +50
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1..ctor(DbDataReader reader, ObjectContext context, MetadataWorkspace workspace, MergeOption mergeOption, Int32 stateCount, CoordinatorFactory`1 rootCoordinatorFactory, Action checkPermissions, Boolean readerOwned) +165
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ShaperFactory`1.Create(DbDataReader reader, ObjectContext context, MetadataWorkspace workspace, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean readerOwned) +93
   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +736
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +149
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +44
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +182
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +41
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +59
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +150
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +102
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +265
   ApplicationBoilerplate.DataProvider.EntityFramework.Repository`1.ReadOne(ISpecification`1 spec) +217
   mvcForum.Web.Extensions.ForumExtensions.GetAccess(Forum forum, Group group) +129
   mvcForum.Web.Extensions.ForumExtensions.GetAccess(Forum forum) +895
   mvcForum.Web.ViewModels.ForumViewModel..ctor(Forum forum, Int32 topicsPerPage) +1353
   mvcForum.Web.Areas.Forum.Controllers.HomeController.Index() +1260
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Small update, I'm using code first. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the exception you get if your entity classes contain properties that are not public--i.e. they are internal, protected, or private. EF5 and below only support mapping to public properties when running in a partial trust environment.

Comment: Don't known whether this was the solution to the mentioned issue, but it solved my issue. Next step: get my unit tests to run in medium trust.